# CSS apply same style to a group of <a> tags

Tags: asp.net, css

First of all, I am totally new in web programming.

I am programming with ASP.NET. I have three links like below:

```
<ul style="margin-top:10px;">
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
</ul>
```

Note that the three dots "..." represents something (it is an example).

What I want is avoid repeating all the time for each link the style, so I create an iD in css file as below:

```
a#myStyle {
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:0px;
}
```

and then apply to all link at once through a div:

```
<ul style="margin-top:10px;">
   <div id="myStyle">
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   </div>
</ul>
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is in the wrong order and you also need a [space](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#descendant-combinators) between the ID value and the [type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) selector, as the `<a>` is a descendant of the div. Use this instead:

```
#myStyle a {
   background-color:transparent;
   padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Applying style Id to only the div section, it applies to all links inside.

Comment: One doubt, as far as I know, the standard css says that declaring an id in css is: element#idname so why here is switched and convention is different (#idname element)? It's asp.net not following the standard? i am a bit confusing. Could you explain me briefly?

Comment: When declaring a selector like `div#hello` you are specifying the [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) that is associated with that ID value. When you use the ID value followed by a [space](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#descendant-combinators) with another selector following it, you are selecting *descendants* of the element with the ID value. So you could also use `div#myStyle a` in your example. The only reason you would use the type selector before it's ID value is for [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) I would think.

Comment: Many thanks, now I understand. Thanks for the links, they help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was correct but you have to switch selectors in your style

```
#myStyle a {
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:0px;
}
```

will change style of all links within DIV with ID #myStyle

Comment: Yes, it works. I have voted @Adrift because he answered first. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the vote! And congrats to @Adrift, let's the fastest gunslinger win :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CSS class instead of an ID, like this:

```
a.myStyle {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Then you can apply the class to each anchor tag, like this:

```
<a class="myStyle" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
<a class="myStyle"  href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
<a class="myStyle" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class, because [you can't give the same id to more than one element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) :

```
<ul style="margin-top:10px;">

   <a class=myStyle href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a class=myStyle href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a class=myStyle href="..."><img src="..."/></a>

</ul>
```

Then your css becomes

```
a.myStyle {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<style>
.anchor
{
background-color:transparent;padding:0px;
}
</style>

<ul style="margin-top:10px;">

   <a class="anchor" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a class="anchor" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
   <a class="anchor" href="..."><img src="..."/></a>

</ul>
```